# Как обратиться к элементу в popup расширения?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, extension

Изучаю создание расширения для Гугл и не могу понять, почему скрипт не может найти элемент во всплывающем окне, которое появляется при клике на иконку этого расширения. В варианте ниже я получаю `null` в консоль. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Payuot from test account",
  "description": "Payout extantion for test account.",
  "version": "0.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Simulation payout",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.com/*"],
      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]

}
```

popup.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>

      body {
        width: 150px;
        height: 15px;
      }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <label><input id="check" type="checkbox" /> Payout on/off </label>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function checkedConfirme() {
  const checkbox = document.getElementById('check');

  console.log(checkbox);
}

checkedConfirme();
```

Comment: А вы проверяли, ваш popup.js вообще работает ? )) сделайте просто console.log('test'). Вы расположили popup.js файл в root ?

Comment: @Arsen да, работает. Без проблем могу найти любой элемент на странице и работать с ним, но с `popup.html` никак не удается.

Comment: Трудно понять в чём загвоздка, просто так разок поменяйте const на var, хотя разницы в вашем примере не должно быть, но просто протестируйте )

Comment: @Arsen не, не прокатило. При чем в документации вообще нет на эту тему ничего, либо я не туда смотрю?.

Comment: Ну значит JS стартует раньше чем завершается загрузка(хотя странно), просто для проверки установите setTimeout на секунду при вызове функции checkedConfirme()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш `popup.js` рабочий, хоть и используете вы его не совсем правильно: в манефесте он указан как в качестве content-script, так и в качестве popop-скрипта для `browser_action` (рекомендуется иметь отдельные скрипты для каждого модуля).

Тем не менее, `popup` – это отдельная веб-страница, и для того, чтобы увидеть результат выполнения скрипта вам необходимо нажать правой кнопкой мыши на иконку в области рашсирений и выбрать там инспектор (последний пункт). В консоле будет искомый элемент.

Comment: ага, понял. Спасибо!